# Check if a string is a number greater than 1

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to check if a string is a number is greater than 1. the string format is Minutes:Seconds = 0:12

this was my approach but sometime i get this error 'list index out of range'

```
length = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/path[2]").text
# length output would be something like 0:28
x = list(length)
    if int(x[0]) < 1:
       print("Less than 1 minute.")
    else:
       pass
```

How can i do this task more efficiently and avoiding getting 'list index out of range' error

Comment: Is `length` a string? Then you can do a simple `if length and int(length[0]) < 1:`. There's no need to make a list out of the string. Of course you might still get an error if the first character can't be transformed to an integer.

Comment: Yes but the length output would have a seperator ":"

Comment: If `x[0]` is out of range, the element had an empty text attribute.

Comment: The example `0:12` led me to a wrong solution. If the minutes can be bigger than `9` you should use `split` as seen in the answer from @jrhode2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `length` will always have `:` between minutes and seconds, you can use the string `split` function to convert it to a list. However, if you are getting a "list index out of range error" you might want to check that `length` has the format you expect.

```
x = length.split(":")
if int(x[0]) < 1:
    print("Less than 1 minute.")
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Using `data = length.partition(':')` could be an alternative approach. If `data[1]` is equal to `':'` we can check if `int(data[0]) < 1`. Otherwise the string has the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you may need to consider the hours as well in the future. The best solution is to use the built-in 'time' module.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str = '13:55:26'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%H:%M:%S')

datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 13, 55, 26) # Now everything you need is easily accessible 

datetime_object.minute # 55
datetime_object.second # 26
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html